# iOS Resource files are duplicated if copied to device

Tags: ios, xcode, resources

If i add folders to my project as references and build the app, it copies the folders with the files to the appname.app folder, but also copies all the files within the folders to the appname.app folder.
I can't figure out how to solve this, any idea is welcome :)

```
----Appname.app
  |
  |--images
  |  |
  |  |--image1.png
  |  |--image2.png
  |
  |--image1.png
  |--image2.png
```

Comment: It doesn't, you probably just didn't clean your project since you changed the folder to a reference.

Comment: I cleaned the project right after i added the reference. (Product->Clean)